# Is there any way to reduce the big CouchDB joins other than list functions?

Tags: couchdb

Using list functions can make a difference when we need server side queries in CouchDB. But here is the problem: Suppose we need some fields from two distinct document types. We may get both documents with the following query:

```
  views: {
    myview: {
      map: function(doc){
        if (doc.type === 'mytype') {
          emit([doc.mykey, 0], {
            field1: doc.field1
          });
          return emit([doc.mykey, 1], {
            _id: doc.theLinkedDoc
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

If we call this view function without `include_docs=true` parameter, it is fetched instantly. If we add `include_docs=true`, fetching the results lasts 10 seconds or so (as the documents are relatively big)

On the other hand, we may use a list function to reduce the results. We need to `include_docs=true` in order to create a useful list function.

My expectation is that as overall result of the list function is tiny (tiny as if we fetched the original view without `include_docs=true` option), this result should be fetched in no time **plus** the list function's execution time (say 2 seconds) but the overall result of the list function is fetched in about 20 or 30 seconds.

Is there any technique to reduce this kind of query efficiently?

Comment: On the first query to your view, you'll likely experience delays because the view index is computed on-demand that first time. (subsequent queries will update incrementally as documents are added/updated/deleted, so they will be faster)

Comment: Also, how big are your documents? You'd have to have really huge documents in proportion to the resources allocated to your database server to have a noticeable impact on performance.

Comment: It depends, but sizes are a few hundred bytes (maybe kilobytes?) per document and there are 600-700 document per view. I'm aware of first index creation process, but this delay is kind of stable and longer than other similar views' first index computation time.